# Django admin index list permission

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Let's suppose I have a `Bar` model with a `owner` field. I want a user to be able to edit all the instances for which `obj.owner == request.user`.

The model appears correctly in the admin panel for superusers and for users for which I have explicitly assigned the permission `change_bar` or `add_bar`, as explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization):

> Assuming you have an application with an app_label foo and a model
>   named Bar, to test for basic permissions you should use:
>
> ```
> add: user.has_perm('foo.add_bar')
> change: user.has_perm('foo.change_bar')
> delete: user.has_perm('foo.delete_bar')
> ```

How can I show the model `Bar` in the admin index list without explicitly assigning `foo.change_bar` or `foo.add_bar` to the user?

So far I tried the following, expecting the `Bar` model to appear in the index list page, but it didn't work.

```
class BarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(BarAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs        
        return qs.filter(owner=request.user)

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return True

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj is None:
            return True
        if obj.owner == request.user:
            return True
        return False

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj is None:
            return True
        if obj.owner == request.user:
            return True
        return False

    def has_module_permission(self, request):
        return True
```

Accessing the link `admin/foo/bar/` works and returns the list of `Bar` instances for which `obj.owner == request.user` and `admin/foo/bar/add` allows the user to add a new object as well.
These links are although not displayed in the admin index page.
`admin/foo/` returns `403 Forbidden`.

I'm using Django 1.7.
Works in Django 1.8.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "foo.change_bar" or "foo.add_bar". Have you registered this class with the admin site?

Comment: I've tried to update the question to make it clearer, but I'm not sure I'm using the proper terminology.

Comment: What you're referring to is multitenancy, which the admin doesn't support very well. There are many attempts at making this easier. Here is one: https://pythonhosted.org/django-guardian/

Comment: OK, everything is correct and working but... only Django >= 1.8